# Why do I get a rosserial_tutorials_tivac catkin_make error?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get this error when running catkin_make for the rosserial_tutorials_ buttons_buttons.axf

/home/pops/Tiva/src/rosserial_tivac_tutorials/buttons/buttons.cpp:28:47: fatal error: rosserial_tivac_tutorials/Buttons.h: No such file or directory
#include "rosserial_tivac_tutorials/Buttons.h"

I have had not difficulty with "chatter" and "chatter129".
I believe I am missing some dependencies in my kinetic distro.

---

### Included contents of my CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rosserial_tivac_tutorials)

## find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS

## geometry_msgs

## message_generation

## rosserial_client

## rosserial_tivac

## std_msgs

#)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
message_generation
rosserial_client
rosserial_tivac
std_msgs
)

add_message_files(
FILES Buttons.msg
)

#add_service_files(

## FILES ColorRGBA.srv

#)

generate_messages(
DEPENDENCIES std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime std_msgs
)

rosserial_generate_ros_lib(
PACKAGE rosserial_tivac
SCRIPT make_libraries_tiva
)

## Because we need to generate our custom messages before exporting our rosserial ros_lib

#add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_ros_lib ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Chatter tutorial

rosserial_configure_client(
DIRECTORY chatter
TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_TIVAC_TOOLCHAIN}
)
rosserial_add_client_target(chatter chatter.axf ALL)
rosserial_add_client_target(chatter flash)
rosserial_add_client_target(chatter size)
rosserial_add_client_target(chatter dump)

## Chatter tutorial for TivaC Connected

rosserial_configure_client(
DIRECTORY chatter129
TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_TIVAC_TOOLCHAIN}
)
rosserial_add_client_target(chatter129 chatter129.axf ALL)
rosserial_add_client_target(chatter129 flash)
rosserial_add_client_target(chatter129 size)
rosserial_add_client_target(chatter129 dump)

## RGB LED tutorial

#rosserial_configure_client(

## DIRECTORY rgb_led

## TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_TIVAC_TOOLCHAIN}

#)
#rosserial_add_client_target(rgb_led rgb_led.axf ALL)
#rosserial_add_client_target(rgb_led flash)
#rosserial_add_client_target(rgb_led size)

## RGB LED service tutorial

#rosserial_configure_client(

## DIRECTORY rgb_srv

## TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_TIVAC_TOOLCHAIN}

#)
#rosserial_add_client_target(rgb_srv rgb_srv.axf ALL)
#rosserial_add_client_target(rgb_srv flash)
#rosserial_add_client_target(rgb_srv size)

## Custom message - Button publisher

rosserial_configure_client(
DIRECTORY buttons
TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_TIVAC_TOOLCHAIN}
)
rosserial_add_client_target(buttons buttons.axf ALL)
rosserial_add_client_target(buttons flash)
rosserial_add_client_target(buttons size)

## How to get a parameter from ROS master

#rosserial_configure_client(

## DIRECTORY getparam

## TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_TIVAC_TOOLCHAIN}

#)
#rosserial_add_client_target(getparam getparam.axf ALL)
#rosserial_add_client_target(getparam flash)
#rosserial_add_client_target(getparam size)

## Time and TF example

#rosserial_configure_client(

## DIRECTORY time_tf

## TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_TIVAC_TOOLCHAIN}

#)
#rosserial_add_client_target(time_tf time_tf.axf ALL)
#rosserial_add_client_target(time_tf flash)
#rosserial_add_client_target(time_tf size)

## Array test tutorial

#rosserial_configure_client(

## DIRECTORY array_test

## TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_TIVAC_TOOLCHAIN}

#)
#rosserial_add_client_target(array_test array_test.axf ALL)
#rosserial_add_client_target(array_test flash)

## freeRTOS for tm4c123gxl

rosserial_configure_client(
DIRECTORY freertos123
TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_TIVAC_TOOLCHAIN}
)
rosserial_add_client_target(freertos123 freertos123.axf ALL)
rosserial_add_client_target(freertos123 flash)
rosserial_add_client_target(freertos123 size)
rosserial_add_client_target(freertos123 dump)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257347/why-do-i-get-a-rosserial_tutorials_tivac-catkin_make-error?/) by [Kenjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29744/kenjr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-20**:
This could point to a problem with a missing `add_dependencies(..)` in the `CMakeLists.txt` of `rosserial_tivac_tutorials`. If you could include a link (or better yet: copy the contents into your question) we could take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There should be no issue with your kinectic distro.

This is an issue with the cmake target `*_roslib`, and the fact that messages are defined in the same catkin package as the rosserial targets. At build time, if target _roslib doesn't find the messages in $PYTHON_PATH, it won't generate them for rosserial targets.

Please try the following procedure:

```
rm devel build -fr
catkin_make rosserial_tivac_tutorials_generate_messages
source devel/setup.bash
catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) with karma: 124 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kenjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29744/kenjr/) on 2017-03-21**:
xxx@home-pc:~/Tiva $ export | grep PYTHON
declare -x PYTHONPATH="/home/xxx/Tiva/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
p

**Comment by [Kenjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29744/kenjr/) on 2017-03-21**:
Tried the procedure you recommended and I get the same results.

**Comment by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) on 2017-03-21**:
Did you delete `build` and `devel` folders before trying the procedure?

**Comment by [Kenjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29744/kenjr/) on 2017-03-21**:
No I didn't.  Got a completely different result, appears to have worked OK.  Should I copy the results to the "Your Answer".

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-03-21**:
@Kenjr, please edit your question to add more information. Also please use the preformatted text layout for your code and console snippets (101010) button to make things more readable.

**Comment by [Kenjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29744/kenjr/) on 2017-03-22**:
Thanks I see the 101010 icon.

**Comment by [Kenjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29744/kenjr/) on 2017-03-22**:
Problem solved I was successful after deleteing the build and devel folders and running the procedure suggested by vmatos.

Thanks